# How to fix Image Overlapping Labels after rotation

Tags: xaml, user-interface, xamarin.forms

After rotating an image, the UI does this on android and iOS (The orange part is the image):
[image: Image Overlap]

The image overlaps some labels and goes behind other labels. Mostly, the image is invading the space of the labels. Any ideas what I can do to fix this?
Here is my Xaml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:maps="clr- 
   namespace:Xamarin.Forms.Maps;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Maps"
         x:Class="App3.ItemScreen"
         xmlns:views="clr-namespace:App3">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Black">
            <views:TopMenu x:Name="myTopMenu" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="200" />
            <Label x:Name="LBL_Title" BackgroundColor="#007374" TextColor="White" HeightRequest="20" />
            <Label x:Name="LBL_ItemPrice" BackgroundColor="#007374" TextColor="White" HeightRequest="20" />
            <Image x:Name="mainImage" HeightRequest="200" />
            <Label x:Name="LBL_Descr" BackgroundColor="#007374" TextColor="White" />
            <Grid>
                <Label Text="Available:" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="#007374" TextColor="White" />
                <Label x:Name="LBL_IsAvail" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="#007374" TextColor="White" />
            </Grid>
            <Label x:Name="LBL_CityAndZip" BackgroundColor="#007374" TextColor="White" />
            <maps:Map WidthRequest="320" HeightRequest="150" x:Name="MyMap" MapType="Street" />
            <Grid>
                <Label Text="Category:" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="#007374" TextColor="White" />
                <Label x:Name="LBL_Category" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="#007374" TextColor="White" />
                </Grid>
                <Button Text="Make Offer" Clicked="BT_MakeOffer_Clicked" BackgroundColor="#002829" TextColor="White" />
                <Button Text="Edit" Clicked="BT_Edit_Clicked" x:Name="BT_Edit" IsVisible="False" BackgroundColor="#002829" TextColor="White" />
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

One idea I have is to move the UI to the CS code, and add the views to the stack after the rotation. I am trying to avoid this for now.

Comment: I see soo many width and height requests in your code, Don't you think it will cause overlapping if there is enough space according to the Layout but not enough screen space?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried removing the heightrequests but it didn't solve the issue

Comment: @JamesCarter After editing it in my local xaml, not finding this issue.Maybe you can share sample , i can check it :)

Comment: @JuniorJiang Thank you for spending the time to try that. Did you remember to rotate the image? The issue occurs when I rotate it. Try changing this one line in the XAML: <Image x:Name="mainImage" HeightRequest="200" Rotation="90" /> . I would post my codebehind but that would be a lot for you to comb through. Putting the rotation in the XAML still causes the issue for me.

Comment: @JuniorJiang Also make sure you start with a landscape image and rotate it to portrait

Comment: @JamesCarter Okey, thanks for explaining , I will try it in xaml. If have solution will update here.

Comment: @JamesCarter Hi, I find the reason why it shows like this when add Rotation.Because rotation is an action to move the object , it won't change the original height and width of the object.And because of View hierarchy, part is up ,part is below.Have to say,this is a normal phenomenon :)

Comment: @JuniorJiang Thank you for the explanation. Looks like I will have to solve this another way then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I solved this issue is to not rotate the image on this screen at all. I am rotating the image before I pass it to the screen.